# Trouble with PDO update

Tags: php, pdo

I am updating a form using PDO's update function. For some reason it is not going through.

Here is code:

```
$data = "UPDATE insuranceverificationdisclaimer SET InsCoName =:insur, PhoneNumber = :phone, Policy = :policy, InsuredName = :insurname
, MailingAdrs = :mailingad, EffDate = :effdate, ExpDate = :expdate, Email1 = :email, YrVehicle = :yr, Make = :make
, Model = :model, VIN = :vin, TraineeUserName = :user, EmpName = :empname, EmpCoName = :empcomp, AgencyNumber = :agnum
, SignDate = :signdate, AgentName = :agname, AgentPhone = :agphone, AgentEmail = :agemail, Combinedlimit = :csl, bodyinjur = :body
, bodyinjureachacc = :acc
, propertydmg = :prop WHERE TraineeUsername = :user";
        echo"1";

$insertdata = $DBH->prepare($data);
$insertdata->execute(array(':insur' => $compname, ':phone' => $phone , ':policy' => $policynum, ':insurname' => $nameofPolicyholder
, ':mailingad' => $newMailingAdrs, ':effdate' => $Policyeffdate, ':expdate' => $Policyexpdate, ':email' => $newEmployeeEmail
, ':yr' => $YearOfVehicle, ':make' => $MakeOfVehicle, ':model' => $ModelOfVehicle, ':vin' => $Vehicleid, ':user' => $username, ':empname' => $EmployeeName, ':empcomp' => $EmployeeCompanyName, ':agnum' => $Agencynum
, ':signdate' => $TodaysDate, ':agname' => $agentname, ':agphone' => $agentphone, ':agemail' => $agentemail, ':csl' => $singlelimit
, ':body' => $bodyinjur, ':acc' => $eachacc, ':prop' => $propertydmg ));
```

Where `, ':csl' => $singlelimit, ':body' => $bodyinjur, ':acc' => $eachacc, ':prop' => $propertydmg` begins this is the function that is not working, these are ints in the database and the values are ints.  If I remove from the select and the array it will work but besides that it will not.

Let me know if you need anything else!

UDATED---------------------------

Wont go through once you hit execute page just stays white.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Wrong result? Exception thrown?

Comment: It does not go through after the execute

Comment: When you get a white page in PHP (a fatal error), you need to turn on display_errors. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on your error reporting as suggested by Michael Berkowski.  For now I can only assume that the error is cause by params datatypes not being defined.  You can try the following:

```
$insertdata->bindParam(':insur', $compname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertdata->bindParam(':csl', $singlelimit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//...bind the other params 
$insertdata->execute();
```